# How do I scrape the explore page of instagram?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to collect the the top 'n' posts from the explore page of instagram.com

I understand that is requires a login, but as it is not exactly a user, 
I am unable to get anything

I am able to collect data for a particular user, even if it private [given that the account whose username and password I am using to scrape the private account follows the required account]

I used [instagram-scraper](https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper) to get the above data

Any help in doing this is appreciated!

When I tried adding the ?__a=1 beside the URL like this https://www.instagram.com/explore/?__a=1, I get only the country name from it.

Comment: Why not using the API?

Comment: For the explore page? If you know how to, can you give more details on that?

I went with this library rather than the API as I didnt have to register before scraping. It was just the easier way. @Pitto

Comment: If scraping was the easier way I'd suppose you wouldn't be ending here, right? :)
I mean no offense, I am just saying that it is probably easier to register and get your data nicely in JSON rather than build some more complicated (and harder to mantain) scraping solution.
Just my two cents.

Comment: @Pitto they are accelerating the depreciation of the API, so scraping is what I would, or most of the people who would see this question, would prefer as well. The library I have mentioned does give it a neat json form.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead add `/grid/?module=explore_popular` so it would look something like [this](https://www.instagram.com/explore/grid/?module=explore_popular). To load the next page you add `&max_id`. The first page doesn't have `max_id` afterwards it starts from 0 with an increment of 1.

E.g:

1. https://www.instagram.com/explore/grid/?module=explore_popular
2. https://www.instagram.com/explore/grid/?module=explore_popular&max_id=0
3. https://www.instagram.com/explore/grid/?module=explore_popular&max_id=1

Be wary that it was intended for making layout NOT getting media data, and as far as I know there isn't any documentation for it.